# HTML - Image on website loads in full quality but then gets compressed when the page finishes loading

Tags: html, css

I have a 1920x1080 image at 300PPI, in local preview the image is crisp and sharp, but when uploaded to the webhost, the image is sharp and when the page is done loading, it goes blurry.

```html
<div class="text-center wide-auto-la animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".5">
    <img src="images/FROMETHWEBSITE/BUYSELLIMAGE7.png" alt="" width="1920" height="1080"> 
</div>
```

What am i doing wrong?

No idea what is causing this honestly

EDIT: I messed up during copy pasting, fixed that.

Comment: Have you tried to empty the cache? Also, you can try to use a more modern image type like `webp`. Also, your `html` has a syntax error that will prevent the `width` and `height` from working correctly.

Comment: I just messed up copy pasting, I don't have these syntax errors in the actual code.

Comment: How are you doing the upload?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're describing might be related to the way the browser loads and renders images. Here are a few potential reasons for the phenomenon you're observing:

Lazy Loading: Some browsers employ lazy loading, a technique where images are loaded only when they come into the user's viewport. Initially, a low-resolution placeholder might be loaded, and the high-quality image replaces it as the user scrolls. Check if lazy loading is being applied to your images.

CSS Styles: CSS styles or media queries might be affecting the image quality after the page has loaded. Ensure that there are no styles applied dynamically that alter the image quality.

Responsive Images: If you are using the srcset attribute to provide multiple image sources for different screen sizes or resolutions, the browser may initially load a lower-quality version and then replace it with a higher-quality version based on the user's device.

Browser Extensions: Some browser extensions or plugins might alter the way images are displayed. Try disabling extensions to see if they are the cause.

Ensure that the HTML and CSS of your page are not manipulating the image quality after the initial load. If the issue persists, inspect the page using browser developer tools to identify any additional factors affecting the image quality.

Answer (score -1):

Compression: Most web hosts compress images to reduce load time. This pressure can reduce image quality and cause blurring. Before uploading, you can try to optimize your image for the website. Save as appropriate (e.g., JPEG for images, PNG for images) and adjust compression settings to balance file size and image quality

Resolution: Check if the image resolution has changed during upload. Once uploaded, make sure the image retains its original resolution of 1920x1080 pixels and 300PPI. Some content management systems or image hosting services may resize the image, which can improve the quality of the images.

HTML and CSS code you provided looks good at first glance. However, the CSS class may be implementing "animated" animation effects that initially make the image appear blurry before stabilizing. You can remove the "animated" category and see if that makes a difference.

Sometimes the way a browser renders an image can affect its perceived sharpness. Make sure your browser won’t distort or resize the image. You can specify the shape of the image as you already did in your HTML, but you also want to use CSS to ensure that it is displayed at its actual size with no scaling

Comment: I just messed up copy pasting, I don't have these syntax errors in the actual code. @HindSagarBiswas

Answer (score -1):

Umm, it's quite simple, you see you have some syntactical problems. You see, you put an unnecessary `>` before `data-delay` attribute as well as before `alt` attribute. This is not only causing syntactical errors but also cutting off the width and height attribute from actually working.

So, this should be your code:

```html
<div class="text-center wide-auto-la animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".5">
    <img src="images/FROMETHWEBSITE/BUYSELLIMAGE7.png" alt="" width="1920" height="1080"> 
</div>
```

This should work I think

Comment: I just messed up copy pasting, I don't have these syntax errors in the actual code.

Comment: I see, so may I ask if the problem was in local environment or live hosted server?

Comment: In local environment the image is sharp with no issues, in live website the image loads sharp but after a second or so it turns blurry. If you open it in a new tab, its still sharp

Comment: Then I think that's most probably network issue... I have faced that a lot and that's why image optimization is used... But I may be wrong, so try different browser or device. Also may I get the link to the page where you are facing the problem to inspect?